# Integrate Storybook CI to Azure CI/CD for a React

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, storybook, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to integrate storybook to my Azure build pipeline for CI/CD. I am finding it a bit difficult so far the pipeline is a simple install/build/archive/publish:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

The official documentation is as follows:
https://www.chromatic.com/docs/azure-pipelines

it does have some examples however, it is an example for different stages, I just want to integrate into master? Any idea's?

Comment: Stage can be used to organize your pipeline job,  it's the major divisions in a pipeline, however it won't affect branch (`master`) used, please check doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml. 
From your yaml, there's no `Chromatic` related. Please check and elaborate a bit more for your expectations, thanks.